# How to pass parameters ByRef to a Form in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, pass-by-reference

So I'm trying to pass the session variable from my main form (LayoutForm) to the Connection form (ConDevForm). Here is the complete code for both my forms. I tried to use the solution given by @LarsTech to do this. But I have failed.

I'm creating the session variable in LayoutForm and then passing it by reference to ConDevForm. Once ConDevForm is closed, I use menu item in LayoutForm to interact with the connected device, in order to verify that I have control of the session through the 'Session' variable.

**This works:**
Main Form

```
Imports NationalInstruments.VisaNS
Imports System.Text
Public Class LayoutForm
    Dim SGFreq As Double = Nothing
    Dim Session As rssmb = Nothing

    Private Sub SMB_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SMB.Click
        Dim Connect As New ConDevForm(Session)
        Connect.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
        Connect.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub MSingle_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MSingle.Click
        Session.GetRFFrequency(SGFreq)
        SGFreq = SGFreq + 1000000000.0
        Session.confRFFreq(SGFreq, 0, 0, 0)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Connection Form

```
Imports NationalInstruments.VisaNS
Imports System.Text
Public Class ConDevForm
    Private sesn As rssmb
    Public Sub New(ByRef sesn As rssmb)
        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()
        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        Me.sesn = sesn
        Try
            UseWaitCursor = True
            System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor
            If sesn Is Nothing Then
                sesn = New rssmb("TCPIP::192.168.138.100::INSTR", 0, 1)
                sesn.confRFFreq(1000 * 1000000.0, 0, 0, 0)
                sesn.confRFLevel(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
            End If
        Catch ex As System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException
            Dim message As String
            message = "Instrument Status Error: " + ex.Message + Environment.NewLine
            message += "Instrument Error Code: " + ex.ErrorCode.ToString("X")
            MessageBox.Show(message)
        Finally
            System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default
            UseWaitCursor = False
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Connect_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Connect.Click

    End Sub
End Class
```

**But this doesn't**

```
Imports NationalInstruments.VisaNS
Imports System.Text
Public Class ConDevForm
    Private sesn As rssmb
    Public Sub New(ByRef sesn As rssmb)
        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()
        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        Me.sesn = sesn
        Try
            UseWaitCursor = True
            System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor
            If Me.sesn Is Nothing Then
                Me.sesn = New rssmb("TCPIP::192.168.138.100::INSTR", 0, 1)
                Me.sesn.confRFFreq(1000 * 1000000.0, 0, 0, 0)
                Me.sesn.confRFLevel(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
            End If
        Catch ex As System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException
            Dim message As String
            message = "Instrument Status Error: " + ex.Message + Environment.NewLine
            message += "Instrument Error Code: " + ex.ErrorCode.ToString("X")
            MessageBox.Show(message)
        Finally
            System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default
            UseWaitCursor = False
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Connect_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Connect.Click

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Under what circumstance is `If Me.sesn Is Nothing Then`?  Your code seems to only use sesn if it's nothing.

Comment: Oh thats just to make sure that the variable isn't a handle to an existing/active session. At the moment since I have declared it as follows

'    Dim Session As rssmb = Nothing'

The condition should be always be true. When things move on from here and I get to add further functionality this will start to make sense, I hope. Anyways the connection does happen even whether I use Me.sesn or sesn. The problem is when I return to LayoutForm, I am unable to interact with the device using 'Session' if I used 'Me.sesn' in ConDevForm.

Answer (score 2):

Add a variable:

```
Public Class Form2
  Private sesn As rssmb

  Public Sub New(ByRef sesn As rssmb)
      InitializeComponent()
      Me.sesn = sesn
  End Sub

  Private Sub connect_Click(...) Handles connect.Click
      Me.sesn=connect(...)
  End Sub
```

If you create a new form, then you would have to re-establish the connection again. So move the reference until *after* your if-check where you might make a new version:

```
Try
  UseWaitCursor = True
  System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor
  If Me.sesn Is Nothing Then
    Me.sesn = New rssmb("TCPIP::192.168.138.100::INSTR", 0, 1)
    Me.sesn.confRFFreq(1000 * 1000000.0, 0, 0, 0)
    Me.sesn.confRFLevel(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
  End If
  Me.sesn = sesn
```

Comment: Hi LarsTech, Thank you for your reply. Will this still act like a reference? that is when i manipulate Me.sesn in Form2, will it actually be manipulating sesn from Form1?

Comment: @AdilMasoudQureshi It won't be a copy.  Try it.

Comment: @AdilMasoudQureshi Also FYI if `sesn ` is a reference type you don't even need the ref keyword.

Comment: @AdilMasoudQureshi : All classes are reference types, while all structures are value types. **Read more:** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx

Comment: That's the thing, I don't think 'sesn' is a reference type. The type 'rssmb' is defined in files that came with the device's drivers that I got from the R&S website. Dunno for sure though, will try in the morning.

Comment: @AdilMasoudQureshi It is.  If it's not the same instance, then you are creating a new instance somewhere in your code.

Comment: @AdilMasoudQureshi Then you are doing something wrong that we can't see in your post.  `solution didn't work` isn't very descriptive either.  It doesn't help us help you without more information.

Comment: @LarsTech Sorry, I was trying to post my code, I was unable to put it in as a comment so I have edited my original problem description. Please take a look.

Comment: @AdilMasoudQureshi Already did.  Already commented on it.  Your code only sets the sesn frequency and levels if it's nothing.  Is the connect click code supposed to be empty?

Comment: yes, it is empty at the moment. I have tried putting the connection code, i.e. the code inside the try-catch. in the connectclick sub. The same thing happens. The device does connect when i click the button. But when i return to LayoutForm I am unable to interact with it using 'Session'.

Comment: @LarsTech,  I think the problem is that the act of connecting involves calling the constructor for rssmb class. Which results in a new instance. But if that's the case should it not result in the same problem when using 'sesn'?